# argument must be a string or a number, not 'LpAffineExpression'

Tags: python, pulp, irr

I am trying to use python IRR function with PULP maximisation but i am getting the following error

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'LpAffineExpression'
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
     11             name[6]*rate[6]*ratesList2[2] + name[7]*rate[7]*ratesList2[2] + name[8]*rate[8]*ratesList2[2] + name[9]*rate[9]*ratesList2[2] + name[10]*rate[10]*ratesList2[2] + name[11]*rate[11]*ratesList2[2] +
     12             name[12]*rate[12]*ratesList2[2] + name[13]*rate[13]*ratesList2[2] + name[14]*rate[14]*ratesList2[2] + name[15]*rate[15]*ratesList2[2] + name[16]*rate[16]*ratesList2[2] + name[17]*rate[17]*ratesList2[2] +

---> 13             name[18]*rate[18]*ratesList2[2])])
     14 
     15

```
problem += np.irr([(-19660528.00),
        (name[0]*rate[0] + name[1]*rate[1] + name[2]*rate[2] + name[3]*rate[3] + name[4]*rate[4] + name[5]*rate[5] + 
        name[6]*rate[6] + name[7]*rate[7] + name[8]*rate[8] + name[9]*rate[9] + name[10]*rate[10] + name[11]*rate[11] +
        name[12]*rate[12] + name[13]*rate[13] + name[14]*rate[14] + name[15]*rate[15] + name[16]*rate[16] + name[17]*rate[17] + 
        name[18]*rate[18]),
       (name[0]*rate[0]*ratesList1[1] + name[1]*rate[1]*ratesList2[1] + name[2]*rate[2]*ratesList2[1] + name[3]*rate[3]*ratesList2[1] + name[4]*rate[4]*ratesList2[1] + name[5]*rate[5]*ratesList2[1] + 
        name[6]*rate[6]*ratesList2[1] + name[7]*rate[7]*ratesList2[1] + name[8]*rate[8]*ratesList2[1] + name[9]*rate[9]*ratesList2[1] + name[10]*rate[10]*ratesList2[1] + name[11]*rate[11]*ratesList2[1] +
        name[12]*rate[12]*ratesList2[1] + name[13]*rate[13]*ratesList2[1] + name[14]*rate[14]*ratesList2[1] + name[15]*rate[15]*ratesList2[1] + name[16]*rate[16]*ratesList2[1] + name[17]*rate[17]*ratesList2[1] + 
        name[18]*rate[18]*ratesList2[1]),
       (name[0]*rate[0]*ratesList1[2] + name[1]*rate[1]*ratesList2[2] + name[2]*rate[2]*ratesList2[2] + name[3]*rate[3]*ratesList2[2] + name[4]*rate[4]*ratesList2[2] + name[5]*rate[5]*ratesList2[2] + 
        name[6]*rate[6]*ratesList2[2] + name[7]*rate[7]*ratesList2[2] + name[8]*rate[8]*ratesList2[2] + name[9]*rate[9]*ratesList2[2] + name[10]*rate[10]*ratesList2[2] + name[11]*rate[11]*ratesList2[2] +
        name[12]*rate[12]*ratesList2[2] + name[13]*rate[13]*ratesList2[2] + name[14]*rate[14]*ratesList2[2] + name[15]*rate[15]*ratesList2[2] + name[16]*rate[16]*ratesList2[2] + name[17]*rate[17]*ratesList2[2] + 
        name[18]*rate[18]*ratesList2[2])])
```

problem += (name[0] + name[1] + name[2] + name[3] + name[4] + name[5] + name[6] + name[7] + name[8] + name[9] + name[10] +
        name[11] + name[12] + name[13] + name[14] + name[15] + name[16] + name[17] + name[18]) <= sum(marketMix['GLA']), "1st constraint"

Answer (score 0):

The numpy function `irr()` takes as argument a list of values. You are instead passing a list of linear expressions containing variables that are subject to optimization. `irr()` is not prepared to handle that. It assumes that all arguments can be coerced into a `float`. Instead of using function `irr()` you will have to state the respective expression explicitly.